# What is the alternative of document.getElementById("id") in case of JSP file?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

In a case of HTML I use `document.getElementById("id");` in order to retrieve my desired `element/tag`.

How can I do that in case of a JSP file (let's say inside a function)?

Comment: JSP will eventually translate to HTML page that will have javascript, so it remains the same.

Comment: let me rephrase. i want an access to my button tag in order to change it's properties after clicking on it. i'm using a function for that, ONCLICK="func()". but the line document.getElementById(..) is not recognized in my JSP. why is that? and how do i gain access to my tag's attributes?

Comment: Could you paste your code. That will give better visibility.

Comment: Whatever you use on the server the output to the browser is always `HTML` so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing the terms HTML, JSP and JavaScript. The `document.getElementById("id")` you mention in your question is a JavaScript snippet that, I guess is enclosed in a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag (which is an HTML tag by the way).

**HTML** is a markup language used to define how web pages looks like (well, actually is CSS the one in charge of the look & feel whilst HTML defines the page layout).

**JavaScript** is an interpreted language often embedded into the HTML and executed by your browser once the contents of the page are loaded.

**JSP** is another markup language based on HTML with several enhancements which allows to create dynamic web pages. JSP is executed by the server instead of the browser and the result of that execution is a HTML document. That generated HTML will contain references to CSS and JavaScript resources if the original JSP had. Even more, the JSP could use its ability to generate "dynamic content" to also generate "dynamic JavaScript snippets".

So, the answer is: ***You can use JavaScript snippets in JSP just the same way you do in HTML code but you can't use it inside Java methods embedded in the JSP as they are processed by the server, not the browser***.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified how you are executing the javascript in a JSP so I'll assume it is in some javascript engine running on the backend Java server. In that situation there is available neither a "document" nor is there getting a document's element since these are artifacts of a browser. These are not part of javascript.

You could prepare a little onload script for the browser if that works for your situation